# Destination with the same identifier

Tags: pdftex, hyperref

first of all, I want to say that I've read many threads to this topic and tried different suggestions to solve this problem but I did not succeed.

I still got this warning while compiling:

> `destination with the same identifier (name{page.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again> \relax l.31 [2]) [3] [4`

My document is of type `\documentclass[twoside, openright, 12pt]{book}`. It has an unnumbered title page followed by an unnumbered blank page. Then I have i, ii, iii, iv and after this pages 1 to n.

I first got the problem after I copied some LaTeX code from another project into my project, so I thought the problem is about things like `\cite`. But then I figured out, that it also occurs when I simply write text. The warnings point to my empty lines. Is it possible that there is something wrong with my line breaks (double enter)?

I use a template of my university, there are many `\usepackage` and other commands. I don't know if I should post everything?! Tell me which information you need.

I include hyperref like this:

```
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle={ein interessantes Thema},
    pdfsubject={Bachelor-/Studienjahres-/Master-/Diplomarbeit},
    pdfauthor={Max Mustermann},
    pdfborder={0 0 0}
}
```

(As you can see, I use the parameters `plainpages=false` and `pdfpagelabels`.)

I would be very thankful if someone could help me solving this issue!

Lukas

---

EDIT:
But there is a further problem I thougt it was related to this topic: When I make paragraphs in my text, I expect them to look like this:
[image: correct paragraph]
This is the case in some situations but in some other cases it looks different:
[image]

Where does the spacing come from?

Comment: Pages that do not show a page number nevertheless have page numbers. So without changing the numbering style the first and second page already have arabic page number 1 and 2. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18924 for more infos. BTW: Usually the title pages are part of the roman numberes pages (if you number the front matter) without showing the numbers. So a simple solution may be to move the page style change to roman in front of the title pages.

Comment: BTW: No, you should not post everything but [make a MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my issue. :-) Its quite difficult to start with LaTex...

Comment: I've edited the question. I thought this problem would be solved with the first one...

Comment: Please do not mix several questions into one. Ask one question per problem and [always show a minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108978/variable-white-space-between-paragraphs

Comment: Thanks again! My problem is solved. And sorry - next time I will create a new question with a MWE.