# How to fix spacing issues?

Tags: spacing, debugging

Might be a waste of time, but  how do I debug excess space that appears in resulting pdf?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-XLQ3t5EINC4ZAs9kk7q5tpM77gpCMjd/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zbsmY26BtSlquhg-4yq1k4HcHxfg5a98/view?usp=sharing

the file might be able to be shortened but I found the spacing is really pronounced if I leave it long

To be clear I would like the algorithm to appear where it does (relative to everything else) but would like spacing to  follow the standard put everything right afterwards unless it's a float that doesn't fit in which case move it to the next page.

Comment: it is not really OK to use a link to overleaf, your question is archived forever and will not make sense if you edit that file.That said you are using `[H]` which _by design_ gives bad white space. figure 6 itself uses `[h]` which is also a bad choice and typically gives a warning that it is changed to `ht`  Every time you restrict the positions that a float may go, you make it more likely that you get  bad spacing at a page break.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  yes but I want the algorithm to appear right there in the text because in the actual writeup I have here is the algorithm  
Also the code here is too long to paste into a post.some of the earlier parts might be able to be deleted, but they make the gap stand out more.

Comment: well if that is on the next page and you prevent it moving, then the page before has to have large white space you can leave it as it is, or add `\clearpage` and force a break with the space at the bottom or you can write some more words to fill the gaps.

Comment: You could post a two page example that shows the problem, although really it's a duplicate of many others

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108978/variable-white-space-between-paragraphs or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172197/tabular-seems-to-create-huge-white-space-between-lines/172232#172232 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33977/how-to-prevent-the-paragraphs-to-spread-out-over-the-page/33981#33981